# Python 2.7 Invalid syntax when running script from .csv file using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, pandas

I am running a script with Python 2.7 using pandas to read from 2 csv files. I keep getting "invalid syntax" error messages, particularly on line 6 and 8. I can't figure out where is the problem, since line 6 is almost identical to line 5 and there I don't get any error. Thanks very much for your help !

```
import numpy as np
import csv as csv
import pandas as pd

da = pd.read_csv('snp_rs.csv', index_col=(0,1), usecols=(0, 1), header=None,    converters = dict.fromkeys([0,1])
db = pd.read_csv('chl.map.csv', index_col=(0,1), usecols=(0,1), header=None,    converters = dict.fromkeys([0,1])

result = da.join(db, how='inner')
x = result.to_csv('snp_rs_out.csv', header=None) # write as csv
print x
```

Comment: close the `()`  in pd.read

Comment: @VigneshKalai should be an answer.

Comment: I'm flagging this post as off-topic since it's a simple typographical error. I wonder how this could get 3 upvotes.

Comment: Thanks very much guys !. I am sorry that Mr Massias got upset. I have been programming for only 1 month...

Comment: The confusing thing is that the error is actually in the previous line.  Python doesn't detect the missing `)` until it starts to process the next line.  It's ok to ask about typographical errors.  We make those all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented you need to close the parentheses around you `read_csv` call:

```
da = pd.read_csv('snp_rs.csv', index_col=(0,1), usecols=(0, 1), header=None,    converters = dict.fromkeys([0,1])
```

It's missing a closing paren.

I find it a lot easier to write/read these if you split the lines:

```
da = pd.read_csv('snp_rs.csv',
                 index_col=(0,1),
                 usecols=(0, 1),
                 header=None,
                 converters=dict.fromkeys([0,1])
```

then it's much clearer that a final `)` is missing.

Comment: sometimes answers for simple typo like this may lead to down votes so did not answer :)

Comment: @VigneshKalai very true. Sometimes I like to live dangerously. :p

Comment: After having 62k and python gold badge you can live dangerously :P